# Forcing Tile Styling on Google Maps API for Javascript V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, wordpress

I am creating a maps plugin for Wordpress that uses Google Maps JS API V3. Commonly the maps will be embedded within a wordpress post that has images that are styled. This actually happens in one of the most popular themes TwentyEleven.

```
.entry-content img,
.comment-content img,
.widget img {
 max-width: 97.5%; /* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
}
```

What this means for Google maps is that map tiles end up looking like is this:

[image: google maps with cascaded style from theme]

This *has* been posted about, not a ton but people have had to deal with it. So I *have* researched this.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/twenty-eleven-12-breaks-embedded-google-maps

http://wpscale.com/google-street-map-cant-work-in-wordpress-3-2/

Every post I have seen on this subject provides the solution of changing the class styling for the div being used:

```
.wl_places_place_map_canvas img {
max-width: none;
}
```

This looks better, it really does. I am not finding a solution that makes it look great though. There are two effects from this solution that are not desirable.

1. Sometimes on backgrounded tile load the styling override doesn't actually work.
2. There is still visible 1px tile gapping that actually gaps marker overlays if they happen to be on tile lines.

[image: google maps with style override]

To deal with the backgrounded style issue I have attempted to use jQuery, and make sure all tiles are loaded prior to setting the style:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(_instance._map, 'resize');
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(_instance._map, "tilesloaded", function() {
 jQuery('.wl_places_place_map_canvas').find('img').css('max-width','none');
 google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);        
});
```

That deals with the first issue, not the second and 1px tile gaps still are visible on the map and overlays.

What I want is a 100% bulletproof way to force style on the map. I have researched the API extensively. What I would *really* like is a way to set the style on the map itself, hopefully as a URL, and it would ignore and override all external styles. In the best possible world this style would live in Google's CDN and be tested to always look clean and fresh no matter where it was embedded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Gotta link to a page that demonstrates this?

Comment: sure do. http://oaklandly.com/?p=373

Comment: Any particular browser? Both maps at that url seem fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added #map img { max-width:none !important; } to the initial map styles. Seems to be working so far.

Everything was working fine for me on WordPress until I added a map inside the HTML field on Gravity Forms. Not sure why it started failing but the above fixed the tile issue.